# The counterpart of python-shell's underscore variable in tcsh?

Tags: python, tcsh

Is there any way to make tcsh keep the output of the last command in a special variable?

I know I can capture the output using backticks, but if I don't use backticks in the first place, it's not captured anywhere. (anyone who likes the underscore variable in the python shell knows what I'm talking about)

E.g.

```
% ls | head -2
% echo $_OUT_
-> myfile1 myfile2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [page](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Special_shell_variables.html) lists the special variables of tcsh and does not specify that there is a special variable for what you are looking for.

Also, here is [a possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3286609/618156) of your question.

Comment: I agree, this is a duplicate of that question. Annoying that you can't submit close votes for questions with bounty.

Comment: Of course I already know there's no such existing special variable.  Despite not getting a satisfactory answer to my question (I'm sure there is a way, it just might not be simple/pretty/conventional, e.g. you can always hack `tcsh`'s code, I was just hoping there's an easier way), I'm accepting your answer as you were the only one who took the time to write an answer ;)